# Can display two record detail with different fields on Account object layout page?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I have one currency field named Full Fleet Potensial and i want display only this currency field only on left side column, middle column i need to display all detail field and right side i need to display activity.

[image]

I can't display only single field on right side column when i drag record detail component it has no filter to display only one field.

is there any way to display single field?

I try to create new layout and try to apply on right side column record detail component but it will change layout for middle record detail component also

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: dynamic forms work on standard objects from Winter'23 onwards.

https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2022/learn-moar-in-winter-23-with-dynamic-forms-on-standard-objects

---

Not out of the box (yet).

The feature to drop single fields on lightning page layout is called "[Dynamic Forms](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_lab_dynamic_forms_ga.htm&type=5&release=228)". <strike>But it works only for custom objects and Account is standard. Keep an eye on roadmap, next releases, maybe there's idea to upvote...</strike>

A developer can create aura or lightning web component with your field, then you'd drop it on that section of the page layout.

If you have VSCode, sfdx configured (bit of upfront investment to set it up but the result will be the bleeding endge of technology SF offers) - look into https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-view-form/documentation. If you don't - in a pinch you can work out of developer console to create Aura version of this component (click the button in upper right of that documentation).

This is also a cool working example if documentation is not your thing: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_load_record. Aura version is here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_load_record.htm

Comment: Post your own answer once you have it working, I'll happily upvote.